# Qt Creator stops highlighting a macro when #define and #undef are located in included headers

Tags: c++, qt, macros, syntax-highlighting

I don't know if it's only Qt Creator thing, or some general issue. The thing is:

```
#define Foo 5
const int value = Foo; //ok, legitly highlighted
#undef Foo
const int value2 = Foo; //ok, legitly not highlighted (here on stack it is anyway, well)
```

Works ok, but when `#define` and `#undef` are located in some headers, then it cracks up:

header with def (`def.hpp`):

```
#define Foo 5
```

header with undef (`undef.hpp`):

```
#undef Foo
```

Now to the example:

```
#include "def.hpp"
const int value = Foo; //ok, legitly highlighted
#include "undef.hpp" // (now, Foo in the upper suddenly not higlighted)
const int value2 = Foo; //not highlighted, ok
#include "def.hpp"
const int value3 = Foo; //bad, Foo is defined but not highlighted 
//(none of Foos is highlighted at this point)
```

I'm using Qt Creator 5.6. Is there any way to maintain correct highlighting?

Comment: Wow, who plays with includes like that and just why... :O

Comment: @MateuszKwasniak certain someone who have read many documentations and language standards, which say nothing about such case. Additionaly this someone is very annoyed that many big environments don't stick to any viable naming standards, providing great opportunities for collisions.

Comment: @MateuszKwasniak Imagine, that you have 1000 macros, where about 50 of them are in collision with a huge library that you actually use. Renaming them? Pretty insane, especially when you are used to their names. This is the best solution I could think of, and does it's job greatly, expect syntax highlighting.